# C compilation error: "expected declaration or statement at end of input"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int r;
    float pi = 3.142;
printf("Enter the radius of circle to find its area");
scanf("%d",&r);
printf("The area of the circle is %d \n", r*r*pi );
    int h;
    printf("Enter the height of the circle to find its Volume");
    scanf("%d",&h);
printf("The volume of the circle is %d \n", h*r*r*r*pi);
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to take input and then calculate the area and volume of circle but getting unexpected errors. The first error is this:

```
practise2.c: In function ‘main’:
practise2.c:4:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Gives me this when i run
[Running] cd "/home/spyder/Desktop/" && gcc practise2.c -o practise2 && "/home/spyder/Desktop/"practise2
practise2.c: In function ‘main’:
practise2.c:4:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
    4 |     {
      |     ^

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.133 seconds
```

Comment: What unexpected errors are you getting?

Comment: practise2.c: In function ‘main’:
practise2.c:4:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Comment: this is first error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the errors.  They get lost in comments.

Comment: @StephenNewell  I have edited

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I compile the program in your question, I get warnings about wrong printf format characters, but not the error you show.

Comment: Are you sure that you have saved the source file? And which compiler are you using? Some will not accept variable definitions not at a block start, and additionally produce misleading diagnostic messages.

Comment: cd "/home/spyder/Desktop/" && gcc practise2.c -o practise2 && "/home/spyder/Desktop/"practise2

Are you not using an ide to run your code??

Answer (score 0):

1. Expresion `r*r*pi` id in `float` type, use `%f` format

`practise2.c:4:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input`

2. Do You maybe have code copied & pasted from net?

Apostrophes may be wrong

Comment: Not working giving same error, should i write this ..? printf("The area of the circle is %f \n", r*r*pi );

Comment: No bro its my own code i have written it myself

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate the error you are describing in your post, please detail your compile flags.

Also, there are a few problems with your code.

1: You should replace all occurrences of '%d' in your code with '%f' so you can accept floating point numbers perform the correct arithmetic.

2: The math in the following line is incorrect to calculate the volume of a cylinder.

```
printf("The volume of the circle is %d \n", h*r*r*r*pi);
```

The above line should in fact be as follows...

```
printf("The volume of the circle is %d \n", h*r*r*pi);
```

Comment: I have edited the wuestion to clearly show you errors pls see

Answer (score 0):

Basic formatting specifiers used with printf (and variants)

```
%c  a single character
%s  a string
%d  a decimal integer (assumes base 10)
%i  a decimal integer (detects the base automatically)
%o  an octal (base 8) integer
%x  a hexadecimal (base 16) integer
%p  an address (or pointer)
%f  a floating point number for floats
%u  unsigned decimal integer
```